# Android 2.3.3 AsyncTask call throws NoSuchFieldError

Tags: android

this works perfectly fine on android 4.0.3 but i get error in android 2.3.3
any help would be greatly appreciated. the line that is bold throws error.

```
public class TestLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Void> {
}

btndownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (util.isNetworkAvailable(NewTakeTest.this)) {
                TestLoadingTask task;
        task = new TestLoadingTask();
        task.currentposition = position;
        task.testname = productsOnCloudList.getList().get(position).getProductname();
        **task.executeOnExecutor(task.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);**
    }
    }
});
```

i am new to stackoverflow so if i am not able to explain my question properly please pardon me.

the entire log is as mentioned below.

```
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: in.informationworks.app.CATapp.store.NewTakeTest$TestLoadingTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): at in.informationworks.app.CATapp.store.NewTakeTest$CloudCustomAdapter$1.onClick(NewTakeTest.java:973)
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2533)
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9320)
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
09-01 17:07:10.853 E/AndroidRuntime(21188): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 17:07:10.863 E/EmbeddedLogger(  180): App crashed! Process: in.informationworks.app.CATapp
```

Answer (score 9):

You have compiled your app using a build target of API Level 11 or higher, but you are running the app on API Level 10 or lower. `executeOnExecutor()` and `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` were added in API Level 11 and do not exist on earlier versions of Android. You will need to use `android.os.Build` to detect what version of Android you are on and use the older `execute()` method on such devices.

For example:

```
  @TargetApi(11)
  static public <T> void executeAsyncTask(AsyncTask<T, ?, ?> task,
                                          T... params) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
    }
    else {
      task.execute(params);
    }
  }
```

To use this, create your `AsyncTask` instance, and call `executeAsyncTask()`, passing the `AsyncTask` object as the first parameter and whatever you want passed to `doInBackground()` as the remaining parameters:

```
fooTask=new FooTask();
executeAsyncTask(fooTask, "these", "are", "optional");
```

Comment: hey Mark, I used this code, including the @TargetApi(11) on my app with minSdk 8. But eclipse still shows error on Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB and AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR (both not available in api v8). What could be the reason?

Comment: @AswinKumar: Your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) needs to be API Level 11 or higher.

Comment: Hadn't quite cared about the target thing. Read up, understood, and it works, thanks :-)